# problem with <g:each>

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am using g:each to iterate the list.My problem is the order of displaying the values is different when i refresh the page or reload the page.
The values must have the same order for each time
My code is

```
 <g:each in="${litter.father.genotypes}" var="type">
  <li><strong>${type.gene.name}:</strong> ${type.value.value}</li>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `litter.father.genotypes` is a `Set`?

If you convert it to a datatype that has an order (`TreeSet`, `List`, etc) the order should remain the same

Comment: How can i convert it to Set in gsp.I just have litter object

Comment: Does: `<g:each in="${litter.father.genotypes as TreeSet}" var="type">` not do it?

Comment: But then I'd suggest that this sort of thing should be covered by the model more than the view

Answer (score 1):

You may be use the sort{} closure that provide a defined order by you:

```
<g:each in="${litter.father.genotypes.sort{it.name}}" var="type">
    <li><strong>${type.gene.name}:</strong> ${type.value.value}</li>
</g:each>
```

In this sample the list is order by genotype's name, you shoul sort the list with the required attribute or an attribute from another class relation.

Regards.